# Unexpected behaviour of js in repeated actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use standart js and jQuery.

I have standart modal window. And since that  have the following mehtods.

```
function closeModal(modal) {
    modal.css('display', 'none');
    return false;
}

function openModal(modal) {
    modal.css('dislay', 'block');
    return false;

}
```

And next using in document:

```
<a href="#ModalAdd" onclick="openModal($('#ModalAdd'))" class="add">Add</a>
```

First time this modal window, opens and closes in a good way. After closing, I can't open it again.

But next commands:

```
$('#ModalAdd').css('display', 'block')

$('#ModalAdd').css('display', 'none')
```

When i use it in browser console, give me needed result.

What issue might it be about?

(I use Ubuntu firfox, if it is important) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the **typo**

```
function openModal(modal) {
    modal.css('display', 'block');
    return false;

}
```

Also **toggle** the display instead.

```
function Modal(modal){
    $(this).toggle(display);
}
```

Comment: Actually it works, thanks.

But what was wrong with my solution?

Comment: You can use the toggle as a better way, as you are already using jquery.